# Changed Nested list items to integer format

Tags: python, regex, list, nested

How do I filter or remove the `.0` at the end of my numbers? I tried converting them to integers but lists don't allow that. Is regex my best option? I don't need to do any maths with the numbers. I just need to remove the `.0` at the end.
all help welcome.

```
Nums  = [['17001.0', '17001.0'], ['17001.0', '11001.0'], ['17001.0', '18001.0'], ['17001.0', '19001.0'],
     ['14001.0', '12001.0'], ['19001.0', '18001.0'], ['19001.0', '16001.0'], ['15001.0'], ['16001.0'],
     ['18001.0'], ['19001.0'], ['18001.0'], ['22.0'], ['22.0'], ['22.0'], ['19001.0']]
```

Comment: You can iterate over loop and can convert to int as =>  int(float('17001.0'))

Comment: substring, regex, double convertion. string opération testing if its a dot. You either don't know how to do basic operation on a list or you wan't to have the best efficient solution. In both case, you should [edit] with what you have try. you can't find the "best" without testting them all so why don't you bench mark every _working_ solution that came into your mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `list` with `integer` elements then this may help you:

```
Nums = [['17001.0', '17001.0'], ['17001.0', '11001.0'], ['17001.0', '18001.0']]
a=[]
for c in Nums:
    if len(c)>1:
        for d in c:
            a.append(int(float(d)))
    else:
        a.append(int(float(c)))

# a= [17001, 17001, 17001, 11001, 17001, 18001]
```

Comment: How is this any different from what I posted?

Comment: @MarkWeston I suppose this as an another simple approach.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would be the simplest approach:

```
nozeros = []
for i in Nums:
    nozeros.append([int(j.split('.')[0]) for j in i])
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried converting them to integers byt lists don't alow that

That's completely wrong:

```
IntNums = []
for lst in Nums:
    IntLst = []
    for n in lst:
        IntLst.append(int(float(n)))
    IntNums.append(IntLst)
```

You couldn't convert strings into integers because they contained the '.0' suffix, but you could first convert them to floats and then to integers.

If you want to convert the list in place, you iterate using indices:

```
for i in range(len(Nums)):
    for j in range(len(Nums[i])):
        Nums[i][j] = int(float(Nums[i][j]))
```

You could use a list comprehension too:

```
Nums = [[int(float(n)) for n in lst] for lst in Nums]
```